# ¿Cómo cambiar un ícono a otro con Javascript y LocalStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

Tengo un ícono que cumple la función de "agregar" una cadena a LocalStorage y otra para "remover", lo que quiero hacer es que sea un solo ícono, si presiono el ícono "agregar" se convierte en el ícono "remover" o al revés ( si esta en remover se convierte en agregar).

Aquí hay un ejemplo de cómo lo quiero. [IMAGE GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gt67u.gif)

```js
function FavId() {
        localStorage.setItem("favn1", "<a href='/details/title'><img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1659560893497-bb094425bd21?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1498&q=80'></a>");
      }
      function Removefav() {
        localStorage.removeItem("favn1");
      }
```

```css
body {
        background-color: black;
      }

      i {
        font-size: 50px;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn-uicons.flaticon.com/uicons-regular-rounded/css/uicons-regular-rounded.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn-uicons.flaticon.com/uicons-solid-rounded/css/uicons-solid-rounded.css'>
    <title>Fav 1</title>
</head>
<body>
  <i onclick="FavId()" class="fi fi-rr-add"></i>
  <i onclick="Removefav()" class="fi fi-sr-cross-circle"></i>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De esta forma te funcionará, he probado en el apartado de añadir condigo de SO y ahí me da problemas con el tema del `localStorage`, no se si probando desde archivos y el navegador esto pasara, por eso tengo esa parte comentada. Pero al menos la parte que quieres tú de los botones funciona correctamente.

Básicamente lo que he hecho es que en la función correspondiente a cada botón enseñe y oculte el otro botón. Y a la hora de cargar la página el botón de `remove` no lo enseñe.

```js
function FavId() {
  // localStorage.setItem("favn1", "<a href='/details/title'><img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1659560893497-bb094425bd21?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1498&q=80'></a>");
  boton_add = document.getElementById("add");
  boton_add.style.display = "none";
  
  boton_remove = document.getElementById("remove");
  boton_remove.style.display = "block";
}

function Removefav() {
  // localStorage.removeItem("favn1");
  
  boton_remove = document.getElementById("remove");
  boton_remove.style.display = "none";
 
  boton_add = document.getElementById("add");
  boton_add.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

i {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#remove {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn-uicons.flaticon.com/uicons-regular-rounded/css/uicons-regular-rounded.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn-uicons.flaticon.com/uicons-solid-rounded/css/uicons-solid-rounded.css'>
    <title>Fav 1</title>
</head>
<body>

  <i onclick="FavId()" class="fi fi-rr-add" id="add"></i>
  <i onclick="Removefav()" class="fi fi-sr-cross-circle" id="remove"></i>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, me funcionó perfectamente